# JQuery .empty(), .remove() or .html('')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Iam trying to delete all the code that is wrapped inside an div.
Here is the code that i nedd to delete.

```
    <div id="btn_flip3" style="position: fixed; top: 80px; left: 5px;" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
    <div class="ui-flipswitch ui-shadow-inset ui-bar-a ui-corner-all ui-mini">
        <a href="#" class="ui-flipswitch-on ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-inherit">On</a>
        <span class="ui-flipswitch-off">Off</span>
        <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" data-mini="true" data-theme="a" class="ui-flipswitch-input" tabindex="-1">
    </div> 
    Test - Text
    </div>
```

So i Need to delete all the code above and i have tried with this

```
$('#btn_flip3').remove();
$('#btn_flip3').empty();
$('#btn_flip3').html('');
```

But non of that deletes everything inside my btn_flip3 div.
The code is generated from users input so the only thing iam sure of is the id of the first div.
So my question is how i should do to delete all the code inside my div with id btn_flip3.

EDIT

I have now tried to add a class and run .remove() on that, but still same result.
When the code have run then the div btn_flip3 is gone but it leaves the code inside it.
So here is the html result

```
<div class="ui-flipswitch ui-shadow-inset ui-bar-a ui-corner-all ui-mini">
    <a href="#" class="ui-flipswitch-on ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-inherit">On</a>
    <span class="ui-flipswitch-off">Off</span>
    <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" data-mini="true" data-theme="a" class="ui-flipswitch-input" tabindex="-1">
</div>
Vardagsrum - Lampa
```

EDIT 2

Okey, maybe this could be a issue with jquery mobile or problem with my code.
Here is how i generate the button part html

```
$('#container').append('<div id ="btn_flip3" style="position: fixed; top: 20px; left: 20px;"><input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" data-mini="false" data-theme="a">Test - Text</div>').trigger("create");
```

This creates an [FlipSwitch jquery mobile](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.4/flipswitch/)

If i just rename the data-role to lets say flipswitch123 so that the flipswitch never gets created (just a simple checkbox instead) then the code works.

Any ide why this is not working with flipswitch?

EDIT 3

I have spent several hours and i cant still get this to work, iam including my tests now, maybe that could some of you experts on this to help me.

Iam using jquery mobile flipswitch and the issue only happens when iam using a flipswitch.

This is how i add the code for the flipswitch

```
$('<div class="btn_flip3" style="position: fixed; top: 20px; left: 20px;">Test - Text<input id="btn_flip3" type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" data-mini="false" data-theme="a"></div>').appendTo('#container').trigger("create");
```

And this is the HTML code that is generated from jquery mobile because the data-role is flipswitch

```
    <div class="btn_flip3 ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="position: fixed; top: 350px; left: 5px;">
btn_flip3
<div class="ui-flipswitch ui-shadow-inset ui-bar-a ui-corner-all ui-mini">
<a href="#" class="ui-flipswitch-on ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-inherit">On</a>
<span class="ui-flipswitch-off">Off</span>
<input id="btn_flip3" type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" data-mini="true" data-theme="a" class="ui-flipswitch-input" tabindex="-1">
</div>
</div>
```

If i now run this code to delete my created div btn_flip3

```
$('.btn_flip3').remove();
```

Then this is what is left in html

```
btn_flip3
<input id="btn_flip3" type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" data-mini="true" data-theme="a" class="ui-flipswitch-input">
```

I find this even more strange, if i change my delete code to this instead

```
$('#btn_flip3').remove();
```

Then the only code that is left untouched is

```
btn_flip3
```

So that did not work, if i now change my original code to

```
data-role="flipswitch1"
```

So that jquery mobile does not make a flipswitch of it then the created code looks like this

```
    <div class="btn_flip3 ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="position: fixed; top: 350px; left: 5px;">
btn_flip3
<div class=" ui-checkbox">
<input id="btn_flip3" type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch1" data-mini="true" data-theme="a">
</div>
</div>
```

If i now run this

```
$('.btn_flip3').remove();
```

Everything is removed.

Anyone have any ides whats going on here?

EDIT 4
This is not an option for me but if i run this

```
$('#container').remove();
```

Then everything gets removed

Comment: may be the id is repeating for some other div as well, make sure id is unique, can you reproduce it in stack-overflow code or jsfiddle?

Comment: Step through your code in a debugger where you're trying to empty it and make sure `$('#btn_flip3')` hits the DOM element you're targeting. If you don't know how to use your debugger, learn!

Comment: It deletes the div btn_flip3 but leaves all the code in the div, and that is not the result that i want.

Comment: try closing the input tag

Comment: The <input> is modified by jquery mobile so even if i add </> in my code then its deleted when jquery mobile does its job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a stange issue, but the only solution that i come up with was to add an extra div.

Original code:

```
$('<div class="btn_flip3" style="position: fixed; top: 20px; left: 20px;">Test - Text<input id="btn_flip3" type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" data-mini="false" data-theme="a"></div>').appendTo('#container').trigger("create");
```

Solution code:

```
$('<div id="helper"><div class="btn_flip3" style="position: fixed; top: 20px; left: 20px;">Test - Text<input id="btn_flip3" type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" data-mini="false" data-theme="a"></div></div>').appendTo('#container').trigger("create");
```

And the delete code:

```
$("#helper").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no problem with your code, mostlikely its because you try to delete the content before the dom is ready.

You can check my working example below

EDIT----

I have tried using dynamic inserted content, its works fine too. Please check if there is any error logged in your browser console log

Regarding data-role flipswitch, thats the identifier that trigger flipswitch js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content").append('<div id="btn_flip3">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectuer adisplicing elit</div>').trigger('create');
    
    $("#js-delete").on('click', function($evt){           
        $evt.preventDefault();
        $("#btn_flip3").html("content deleted");
  });
});
```

```css
#content{ margin-bottom:20px; }

.control-box{
  padding:20px;
  background:#eee;
  border:#ddd solid 1px;
}

#js-delete{
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding:4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>

<div class="control-box"><a id="js-delete">Delete Dynamic Content</a></div>
```

Comment: you can try post your complete html and js so we can properly checking it

Comment: Edited my first post with some information about this issue.

Comment: why you require a trigger in there?

Comment: Maybe i dont :) but its not causing this issue.

Comment: my advise is, check your browser console log, see if there is any error logged in there. Second, check if the trigger you use to remove is working or not, perhaps mistyping its id or something else

Comment: No error in the console, please look at my last edit.

Answer (score 0):

try my edited answer :

```
$('.my_class').next('div').remove();
$('.my_class').remove();
```

Comment: I don't think that he wants to remove that div - rather he wants to delete everything inside of it.

Comment: OP could try that... but why?

Comment: maybe there are another div who have the same ID :)

Comment: if you want to delete everything inside the div and let the div in the DOM you must use .empty

Comment: Explain that in your answer.

Comment: the $('.my_class').remove() remove method delete the entire div from the document, but the $('.my_class').empty() delete the content of the div but not the div :)

Comment: Please look at my edit in my post.
i want to delete all code inside the div and also the div itself

Comment: Just a note. @ZakariaWahabi mentioned above that "another div who have the same ID". I don't think that's supposed to happen. ID should be unique to a node

Comment: i have tested this and its work with the id , try to add a click event on the div and alert its content and maybe you have an issue with the html or somthing

Comment: The ID is only in one place, well actually in both ID and Class but that should not cause any issues.
Look at my last edit, you will see that the works if i dont make a flipswitch from my code.

Answer (score 0):

First Make sure your DOM is ready with

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // then call remove function 
  $('#btn_flip3').remove()
});
```

Comment: The DOM is ready, iam calling this function from a double click so there is alote of time for the page to become ready beffor i fire this up.

Comment: You should try what he says. If the element is not there yet, the function will not point to any element. It doesn't matter how much time the user takes to double click the element if the browser parse the script before drawing the element.

Comment: But the element is there, i checked in "Elements" in chrome